# Using Sessions in an ASP.NET 4.0 Log-In Control

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0, authentication

I'm currently developing a website using Visual Studio 2010. As you all might know, creating a new website here automatically adds an Account folder which contains webpages like Login.aspx, etc. I am implementing this Login.aspx which contains the ASP.NET Login control. It's now functioning the way it should but I have a few concerns.

Before, I used to create my own UI for the log-in so managing sessions is not a problem to me. But since i'm currently using the Login.aspx which has a CS file almost empty, i don't have an idea where I can start implementing my session. Meaning to say, I don't know how to check programatically if the user has been successfully logged in so I can start implementing my session.

I would very much appreciate any pointer regarding this matter.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are events associate with [ASP.NET Login Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) that you can use to create session like [OnLoggingIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggingin.aspx). Moreover you can find more about user validation from here [Validating User Credentials Against the Membership](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/validating-user-credentials-against-the-membership-user-store-cs)

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe for the [Authenticate event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx) and perform some custom authentication logic. Also you may take a look at the [following article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/LoginControl07242008104351AM/LoginControl.aspx).